# printf("%%%s","hello")

Tags: objective-c, c

If I write `printf("%%%s","hello")`, how is it interpreted as by the compiler? Enlighten me, someone.

Comment: The compiler can enlighten you.

Comment: @BlotClock I admit it, I chuckled

Comment: @BoltClock : The compiler provides me with an answer and not an explanation :D i actually wanted a mortal to answer this for me :D

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The compiler simply interprets this as calling `printf` with two strings as arguments (but see Zack's comment).

#### This happens at compile time (i.e. the compiler does this):

The strings (`"%%%s"` and `"hello"`) are copied directly into the executable, the compiler leaves them as-is.

#### This happens at runtime (i.e. the C standard library does this when the app is running):

`printf` stand for 'print formatted'. When this function is called, it needs at least one argument. The first argument is the format. The next arguments are "arguments" to this format. They are formatted as specified in the first argument.

[image: img]

---

## About optimization

I have written an example and ran Clang/LLVM with `-S`:

```
$ emacs printftest.c
$ clang printftest.c -S -o printftest_unopt.s  # not optimized
$ clang printftest.c -S -O -o printftest_opt.s # optimized: -O flag
```

### C code

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
  printf("%%%s", "hello");
  return 0;
}
```

### printftest_unopt.s (not optimized)

```
; ...
_main:
    pushq   %rbp
    movq    %rsp, %rbp
    subq    $16, %rsp
    movl    $0, %eax
    movl    $0, -4(%rbp)
    movl    %eax, -8(%rbp)
    xorb    %al, %al
    leaq    L_.str(%rip), %rdi
    leaq    L_.str1(%rip), %rsi
    callq   _printf               ; printf called here <----------------
    movl    %eax, -12(%rbp)
    movl    -8(%rbp), %eax
    addq    $16, %rsp
    popq    %rbp
    ret

    .section    __TEXT,__cstring,cstring_literals
L_.str:
    .asciz   "%%%s"

L_.str1:
    .asciz   "hello"
; ...
```

### printftest_opt.s (optimized)

```
; ...
_main:
    pushq   %rbp
    movq    %rsp, %rbp
    leaq    L_.str(%rip), %rdi
    leaq    L_.str1(%rip), %rsi
    xorb    %al, %al
    callq   _printf               ; printf called here <----------------
    xorl    %eax, %eax
    popq    %rbp
    ret

    .section    __TEXT,__cstring,cstring_literals
L_.str:
    .asciz   "%%%s"

L_.str1:
    .asciz   "hello"
; ...
```

### Conclusion

As you can see (in the `__TEXT,__cstring,cstring_literals` section **and** the `callq` to `printf`), LLVM (a very, very good compiler) does **not** optimize `printf("%%%s", "hello");`. :)

Comment: The compiler *might* (but is not required to) interpret it for optimization purposes.  The compiler is allowed to know what the standard says the `stdio.h` functions do, and to make optimizations based on that knowledge -- for instance, `printf("%%%s", "Hello")` could be transformed to `printf("%%Hello")` or even `fputs("%Hello", stdout)` in the executable.

Comment: @Radek Pro-Grammer I do not think that the compiler interprets it as having two string arguments...if that had been the case then printf("Hello\t","World\n") would have given us Hello World...but i get Hello as the output...

Comment: @phoenix the compiler still interprets it as a call to `printf` with two strings as argument. These strings are `"%%%s` and `"hello"`. That doesn't mean that the **C standard library** does not interpret it! `printf`'s first argument is the **format** to print the next arguments in, and this **format** is interpreted at runtime (when the app is running), not compile time.

Comment: @Radek Pro-Grammer If that is the case then probably when i say printf("Hello","World") the compiler looks for the format specifier and when it does not find one,it takes only the first argument as the input choosing to neglect the second...is this what happens???

Comment: @Radek Pro-Grammer and this is probably i get the o/p as Hello...i hope i am right this time!!!

Comment: @phoenix the compiler does not look at what you enter as arguments. The C standard library does this. The fact that `"Hello"` does not contain any format specifiers (`%s`, `%c`, `%d`, etc) means that the next arguments (in this case just `"World"`) won't be used.

Comment: @phoenix For example: I could do this: `printf("Hello %s", "World")` and `Hello World` will be printed. The format is `Hello %s`. `%s` is replaced by the second argument (`"World"`). If I'd do this: `printf("Hello %s %s", "cruel", "world");`, the output will be `Hello, cruel world`. `%s` means string. `%%` means a percent sign, an [escape sequence](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Escape_sequence).

Comment: @Radek Pro-Grammer : Thanx so much mate for enlightening me :D

Comment: i learnt quite a bit today from this thread and my doubt stands cleared...must admit that!!!

Comment: @phoenix read [this](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cstdio/printf/) and try some things (you might want to read it multiple times, it's a good document). It'll get more clear when you use it often. Have fun! :)

Comment: @phoenix: Nice Question and @Radek Pro-Grammer: Great explanation..Thanks :)

Comment: Why hasn't this post reached a 2-digit score yet?

Answer (score 7):

"%%" means to print an actual "%" character; %s means to print a string from the argument list. So you'll see "%hello".

Comment: So can i write printf("%%Hello");

Comment: @phoenix Yes you can, but that doesn't give printf any real work to do, so it would be better written `fputs("%Hello", stdout)`.

Answer (score 1):

%% will print a literal '%' character.